# QGIS - Disable Mouse Wheel Zoom

Tags: qgis, zoom, user-interface, mouse-wheel

I'm using QGIS 2.16.x and the mouse wheel preference to disable zooming does not seem to be available. I've tried locking the scale but when the magnifier function is enabled, the zoom function still responds to the mouse wheel.

Is there any way to disable mouse wheel zooming in QGIS?

Comment: Just confirming mouse wheel action is missing in 2.16 - Map Tools - Panning and zooming. You might need to add this as new issue into http://hub.qgis.org/ if you want this functionality.

Answer (score 8):

In QGIS 2.14.7 LTR there is an option to completely disable zooming using the mouse wheel from `Settings -> Options -> Map Tools -> Panning and Zooming`, you need to change Mouse wheel action to `Nothing` as you can see below:

[image]

However, the same option is not available in QGIS 2.16.3. But there is a new option called `Magnification`. When you lock the scale in QGIS and zoom using mouse wheel, the zooming here is not actually zoom but magnify the view of the screen.

I recommend to install QGIS 2.14.7 LTR to disable the mouse wheel completely, if you need this option.

Comment: Unfortunately 2.18.9 is missing the the ability to disable the mouse wheel on the mac. Makes the entire thing unusable IMHO.

Comment: @swa66 You can use QGIS 2.14.16 LTR which still has this option.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I guess the mouse wheel action has become a default setting in QGIS 2.16.x. If you go to `Settings > Options > Map Tools > Zoom factor`, you will see the minimum value possible is `1.1`. Makes sense since a factor of `1` for a given value will remain the same. So let's change the zoom factor to `1` using Python!

Paste the following in the **Python Console**:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/zoom_factor", 1)
```

For QGIS 3.x:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/zoom_factor", 1)
```

Restart QGIS and now your mouse wheel has become *'disabled'*.

---

*Note that the zoom factor will always be shown as `1.1` as that is the minimum value allowed to be shown in the widget. Also, if you go back to the Options menu and you click OK, the zoom factor will be reset to `1.1`. So you will need to use the code and restart QGIS again.*

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but without results. Paste the code, restart, but again mouse wheel zoom over the map. Thanks for help.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I'm using QGIS 2.16.1 on Windows 7 64-bit. Works fine for me so not sure what's going on in your end. But thanks for adding that as a _feature request_ =)

Comment: Doesn't work on Qgis 2.18.15 on macOS. It's not that I'd have to have it be disabled, but it's is *far* too reactive the smallest touch on a mouse surface that's not 100% unmoving results in the map wildly scrolling way in or way out. I guess with old fashioned mice that have clicking scroll wheels this might work, but the sensitve stuff we mac users tend to use is FAR too accelerated in Qgis. Instead of accelerating it, it needs to be slowed down by a factor of 10 or more IMHO.

Comment: @swa66 - You should probably [submit a ticket](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis) for this, they could hopefully provide a fix for this in their next iteration :)

Comment: Tried a few scroll related tickets for mac earlier. One got closed already because it was fixed in 3.0, and they did not want to backport. That still leaves us stuck with no 3.0 build for mac, no more 2.14 and a 2.18 that's pretty hard to use due to it lacking what 2.14 had and not getting whatever magic is coming with 3.0

Comment: @JayCummins - Thank you for adding the solution for QGIS 3.x :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct spelling would be `qgis` rather than `Qgis`:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/qgis/zoom_factor", 1)
```