# Disable map zooming with QGIS 3.5 +

Tags: qgis-3

I am trying to disable zooming with the mouse wheel for QGIS 3.8. Past versions have had an option to under `Settings/Preferences` -> `Map tools`, but this appears to have moved with the newer versions.
I am trying to just lock the layer scale similar to how Arc allows for the zoom layer to be locked. Disabling mouse wheel zoom will work for my situation since I am using a Mac magic mouse which is very easy to accidentally scroll with.

Comment: I looked for that setting under settings>options>map tools in QGIS 2.18, 3.4, and 3.8 on windows and didn't see it. What version did you find it in? There is a lock button at the bottom of your screen that doesn't prevent scrolling but make the map magnify instead of re-scaling.

Comment: Looks like you question has been answered here :https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215326/qgis-disable-mouse-wheel-zoom unfortunately it seems like there is no longer a button but I tried the python code and it worked. Maybe open a feature ticket.

Comment: I never found the button to lock the scale, I was basing that statement off the answer to a similar question that @Baswein linked to. I tried the python code and it did not work for me. Running Q 3.8 on a Mac.

Comment: That sounds like an annoying situation. You might try the suggestion in the other post about not capitalizing the q in Qgis in the python code. There is a feature ticket out for this but nothing has happened in a few years. If you have a Retina display it might be related to that like in this issue. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18418 A shot in the dark but you could try a number lower than 1 in the python code.